# Why is re-added click event not firing?

Tags: jquery, html

My html is rendered like this:

```
<td colspan="2" onclick="reportTypeClick(this);" class="menuItem oneTest">...</td>
```

Now I want to disable/enable the td as well as the click event:

```
if(...) {
    $('.oneTest').removeClass('menuItem').addClass('menuItemDisabled')
    .attr('onclick', '');
} else {
    $('.oneTest').removeClass('menuItemDisabled').addClass('menuItem')
    .attr('onclick', 'reportTypeClick(this);');
}
```

The `if` works as expected, but the `else` doesn't.  That is to say, I get no script errors, but the event fails to fire.

Any ideas?

Looks like it has something to do with **this**.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Could you post a [JS Fiddle demo, that reproduces your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: If possible, you're probably better off removing inline event handlers and using jQuery's `.click()` and `.bind()` functionality like @JMax says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `onclick` attribute and use jquery event handling..

```
if(...) {
    $('.oneTest').removeClass('menuItem').addClass('menuItemDisabled')
    .unbind('click');
} else {
    $('.oneTest').removeClass('menuItemDisabled').addClass('menuItem').each(function(){
      var _this=this;
      $(this).bind('click', function(){ reportTypeClick(_this) ););
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could alter your `reportTypeClick` function..

```
function reportTypeClick(element)
{
  if ( $(element).is('.menuItemDisabled') ) return; // add this line as the first line ..

  // the current body of the function should follow..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the event via the `attr` function, could you use the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function ?

[edit] and unbind it with the jquery [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function ?

Regards

Max

Comment: I think I'll have the same problem.